# How to include archive template file through plugin

Tags: wordpress, custom-taxonomy

I have registered a custom taxonomy `wfa_book_genres` through plugin and the slug name for this taxonomy is `genres`.

Now i want to include archive template from plugin folder for my custom taxonomy. I tried to use below examples code but it shows completely blank when goes to that archive term. I don't know how to solve this issue. I am really stuck here:

```
add_filter('template_include', 'wfa_taxonomy_template');
function wfa_taxonomy_template( $template ){

 /*
  // if wfa_book_genres taxonomy
  if( is_tax('wfa_book_genres')){
    $template = plugin_dir_url(__FILE__ ).'taxonomy-wfa_book_genres.php';
   }
  */

  // if wfa_book_genres taxonomy slug
  if( is_tax('genres')){
    $template = plugin_dir_url(__FILE__ ).'taxonomy-wfa_book_genres.php';
  }  
  return $template;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

change **plugin_dir_url** with **dirname**:

```
    $template = dirname(__FILE__ ).'taxonomy-wfa_book_genres.php';
```

Comment: Hi Bhumi, i changed it but still same issue. When the taxonomy archive page open its shows completely blank. Without condition i included this template also, but no luck :(